# Best practice for getting user input from multiple methods in Java?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner, user-input

I have a relatively basic program in which I have several methods getting input from the user (using a Scanner object). I am looking to see which of these techniques (if either) is considered standard or best practice. Here I will use one method just as an example.

1. Create a new scanner object in each method separately:

```
// Get date from user
public static LocalDate getDateFromUser(String date_request_label){

    Scanner inputScan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print(date_request_label + " (YYYYMMDD): ");
    String input_string = inputScan.nextLine();

    // Split input into year/month/day
    int year  = Integer.parseInt(input_string.substring(0,4));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(input_string.substring(4,6));
    int day   = Integer.parseInt(input_string.substring(6,8));

    return LocalDate.of(year,month,day);
}
```

2. Create a single scanner object in main and call it in each method:

```
// Get date from user
public static LocalDate getDateFromUser(Scanner inputScan, String date_request_label){
    System.out.print(date_request_label + " (YYYYMMDD): ");
    String input_string = inputScan.nextLine();

    // Split input into year/month/day
    int year  = Integer.parseInt(input_string.substring(0,4));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(input_string.substring(4,6));
    int day   = Integer.parseInt(input_string.substring(6,8));

    return LocalDate.of(year,month,day);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I also agree that creating and re-using one `Scanner` is almost always preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO reusing an object is preferable as long as it does not reduce the readability of the code.

So I'd go with option two.